# Column delimiter error in copy data in azure data fabric

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

i'm facing a problem while I'm trying to create a "copy data" action in azure data fabric. I'm getting the following error "Column delimiter cannot be empty string or multi-character string" when setting the column delimiter to no delimiter for the source file as I want the whole line to be treated as one column.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gx3dM.png

Am I missing something here? Why I'm getting this error?

Comment: What happens if you choose a delimiter?

Comment: Then the error message disappears.

Comment: did you try using copy data active in pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

As i know, only one character is allowed.Multiple character delimiter is not supported which is stated in the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#text-format).

If you don't want any format change, you could use binary copy.

Otherwise, maybe you could consider [custom activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-dotnet-custom-activity).